# ogrinfo: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name

Tags: gdal, spatialite, geodjango

On trying to execute `ogrinfo` i got this error:

```
ogrinfo: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name
```

I got this on one of my PCs, though on the others it works well. Seems like i installed something which prevents gdal of working normaly. May be i removed something trying to get it work, or may be i installed a lot of useless packages, but it seems that i've tried everything. [python gdal - libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199489/python-gdal-libgdal-so-1-undefined-symbol-sqlite3-column-table-name) didn't help me as well as a lot of other solutions. I think the best option is to somehow remove all dependencies gdal made to make it work. If someone knows how to fix this or may be hint me about packages i should uninstall to install it in correct order.

- spatialite-bin
- libsqlite3-mod-spatialite
- GEOS
- PROJ.4

When i'm trying to start my django application which uses gdal and spatialite i got this error:

`OSError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspatialite.so.7: undefined symbol: sqlite3_create_function_v2`

Comment: I have encountered this problem on library mismatches. Can you locate all libgdal and sqlite  on your PATH?

Comment: I tried to localte and remove all libraries with synaptic whose name consists `gdal` or `spatialite` and reinstall it afterward but at the end i got this message `ogrinfo: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20`

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: Did someone solve this error? I do have the same issue. Starting gazebo causes the following error symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name

Comment: I ended up totally reinstalling Ubuntu and installing all gis stuff from scratch.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134511)

Comment: Remove /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.* files, solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Answers here are expected to be at least one, and generally a couple of paragraphs. If you're going to recommend removal of libraries outside of package management, you *really* need to explain ***why*** it is necessary.

Comment: @TommasoMerciai thanks

Comment: Oh man @TommasoMerciai, You made my day!!

Comment: check this solution https://blog.csdn.net/qq_38979769/article/details/129723825